# (Sobolev space) A star domain in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

We know the **theorem**:

> - If $\Omega$ is a *star domain* in $\Bbb R^n$, then $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ is *dense* in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.
>
> It means that $\overline{C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})}=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$

==========================================================

- I have a question (I have trouble when I learn about Sobolev space):

$a.$ For example:

Let $\Omega=[-1,1]\times [-1,1] \setminus\{x=0,y \ge \dfrac{1}{2}\}$.

[image: picture]

Can anyone post a function $u$ such that:

$$\exists u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) \not \to \exists \{u_n\} \subset C^{\infty}(\Omega)$$
$$\|u_n-u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} \to 0$$

$b.$ If $\Omega$ is **not** a star domain in $\Bbb R^n$ then a *domain* $\Omega$ needs the *properties* so that $$\overline{C^{\infty}(\Omega)}=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$
?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $\{x=0,y\ge 1/2\}$? Also, can you refer to some book where can I find this statemente about star shaped domains?

Comment: An example for (a) can be $u(z)=|z|\arg z$ (using complex number notation). This is in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, but cannot be approximated by functions that are continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$. This domain happens to be star-shaped, too. Which raises a few questions: what exactly is a star domain? What exactly is $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$? Do you mean    $C^\infty( {\Omega})$ in (b)?

Comment: @ **Tomás** and **user103402**: A set $S$is called a    **star domain** (or star-convex set, star-shaped or radially convex set) if there exists $x_0 \in S$ such that for all $x \in S$ **the line segment** from $x_0$ to $x$ is in $S$.

Comment: @ **user103402** : $$C^{\infty}(\Omega)=\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}C^k(\Omega)$$ where $$C^k(\Omega)=\{u:\Omega \to \Bbb R^n \mid D^{\alpha}u \ \text{is continuous in} \Omega, |\alpha| \le k \}$$ For b) $\overline{C^{\infty}(\Omega)}=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ not $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$.

Comment: Where do you found this result on star shaped domains?

Comment: @ **Tomás**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain It's  the same as my prof said.

Comment: I added the picture for your first question.

Comment: Sorry @kimtahe6. I think I have not made my question clear. I mean where did you find the result about the denseness property for Sobolev spaces defined in star domains?

Comment: Yes,**Tomás**, I understand your question :). The result about the denseness property for Sobolev spaces which in my book (as I said "My prof wrote it") and you can find The result $$\overline{C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})}=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$ if $\Omega$ is a star domain from the book **Linear Partial Differential Equations** by **James C. Robinson**. But My question is "If $\Omega$ is **not** a star domain, then We need to find what the conditions for **domain** so that it holds (for b). What about a)? Thanks!

Comment: SOrry @kimtahe6, but I can't find this result of denseness nowhere, nor I can find this book you have cited. Are you sure this result is true. Do you have another source to cite? THank you

Comment: Do you mean the result $$\overline{C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})}=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$ if $\Omega$ is a star domain? **Tomás**

Comment: Yes @kimtahe6, this resutl.

Comment: I think it's correct (Because my prof wrote in his book :)   ;It has a proof). But I don't understand it.

Comment: Can you scan the Theorem and the proof and link here? @kimtahe6

Comment: Yes, I'll write it here. Ok!

Comment: **Theorem 1.2.3** Assume that $\Omega$ is a **star domain** with origin. And $f \in L^p(\Omega), p \ge 1, f(x)=0, x \not \in \Omega$. Whence, $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists \delta >0$ such that $$\int_\Omega|f(x)-f(\lambda x)|^p\rm d x <\epsilon ,\ \text{if} \ |\lambda -1|<\delta$$ **Theorem 1.2.4** Assume that $\Omega$ is a *domain* in $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Omega'$ is a subdomain of $\Omega$ such that $\overline{\Omega'} \subset \Omega$. If $u \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ then $$\lim_{h \to 0}\|u_h-u\|_{W^{k,p} }=0$$.

Comment: **Proof** Assume that $\Omega$ is a star domain in $\Bbb R^n$ with origin. If $u \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ then function $u(\lambda x)$ defined in $\Omega_1=\{x \in \Bbb R^n: \lambda x \in \Omega\}$, where $\lambda$ is const, $\lambda<1$ and $u(\lambda x)  \in W^{k,p}(\Omega_1)$. Moreover, for all $\epsilon >0, \exists \delta(\epsilon)>0$ (**theorem 1.2.3**) such that $$\|u(\lambda x) -u(x)\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}\le \epsilon$$ if $|\lambda -1| < \delta(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Since the **theorem 1.2.4**, we have $$\lim_{h \to 0}\|u_h(\lambda x) -u(\lambda x)\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}=0$$ Hence, $$\lim_{h \to 0}\|u_h(\lambda x) -u(\lambda x)\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)} \le \epsilon$$Because $u_h(\lambda x) \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ then we're done.

Comment: Well, the set that you have defined is star shaped with respect to the origin, hence, by the result you have posted here, it is impossible to construct such example. However, I did not made the calculations, but it seems that @user103402 provided a counter example in the case where $p=\infty$.